# Getting the csinterface_derived to work when swiging C# interfaces

Tags: c#, swig

I have the following class inheritance pattern in a c++ header file.

```
class Base{  
public:
  virtual ~Base() = default; 
};
template<class T> class Container : public Base{ 
public:
  ~Container () override = default;
  // The rest of implementations
};
```

I have exported the Base class to C# and want to create a c# interface for Container that implements the IEnumerable. from the [documentation](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/CSharp.html) It seems that I need to use the csinterfaces_derived. I cannot get it to work with the following patters. The IEnumerable will be missing even if I switch the order of the two following lines. Any suggestions?

```
%typemap(csinterface_derived) Container<int>  “IEnumerable<int>";
%template (ContainerOfInt) Container<int>;
```

Comment: What version of SWIG are you using?  The link you provided looks like a very old version.  Your link may not be the same as version you are using.  See : https://www.swig.org/

Comment: I use the latest version of swig. The latest documentation for using csinterfaces and csinterfaces_derived is available in https://www.swig.org/Doc4.1/CSharp.html#CSharp which is not very different from the link that I shared.

Comment: I always check the date of documentation and sample code.  Old code often fails.  There was not dates on the webpage, but some of the code had a date of 2014.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in `%typemap(csinterface_derived)`.
Should be `%typemap(csinterface`**s**`_derived)`

Also, even if the `Container<T>` template class happens to inherit from another base class, if actual C# custom code is injected (via `%typemap(cscode)`, to implement the `IEnumerable<T>` via the magically-named method `public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()`, then one doesn't need to explicitly affect / impact the resulting SWIG C# class wrapper's inheritance, i.e. no need to explicitly indicate `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` as inherited / implemented C# interface. And in such case, using `%typemap(csinterface`**s**`)` should also work.

But if it's desired to have SWIG C# class wrapper implement other commonly-used C# interfaces (the `System.IDisposable` for example), then using `csinterfaces_derived` is a must.

Somehow the Cpp-to-`someOtherSupportedPgmLang` implementation part of SWIG seems to be less flexible than Java-to_`someOtherSupportedPgmLang`. In the sense that, for source lang = C++, the lexical analyzer and grammar / parser is more complex, and SWIG therefore needs to know explicitly if one wishes to append more base classes / Interface to target C++ class' inheritance chain. Probably because it will spawn additional, and more time-consuming logic, to find out the existing C++ base classes, where their definitions are, proper inheritance order etc, and then adding new base type names.